# retrieve all events within a domain using Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to retrieve all the events programmed within a domain `entreprise.tn` using Google Calendar API.

On google admin console, I create a new project and a new service account with `owner` role as described by [that thread](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation).

I enabled Google Calendar API and Admin SDK like described by [that thread](https://spaceconnect.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000510755-1-Activate-your-Google-Calendar-API-and-Admin-SDK).

the list of scopes added on **Admin console>Security** are :
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly

My code is:

```
        Calendar service = getCalendarService();
        List<Event> items = new ArrayList<Event>();
        String pageToken = null;
        do
        {
            Events events = service.events().list("service-account-esp1@my-first-project-274515.iam.gserviceaccount.com").setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
            items = events.getItems();

            for (Event event : items)
            {
                System.out.println(event.getSummary());
            }
          pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();
        } while (pageToken != null);

        if (items.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Empty");
        }
        else
        {
             System.out.println("Exists");
        }
```

the file `my-first-project-274515-361633451f1c.json` is the generated file when creating the service account and performing G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.

the `service-account-esp1@my-first-project-274515.iam.gserviceaccount.com` is the **client email**

It looks ok, all the required configurations are done.
How evere, I got that exception:

> avr. 18, 2020 12:28:59 PM
>   com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory
>   setPermissionsToOwnerOnly AVERTISSEMENT: Unable to set permissions for
>   C:\Users\Administrateur\credentials, because you are running on a
>   non-POSIX file system. Charge Calendars: Sat Apr 18 12:28:59 BST 2020
>   a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException   at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:128)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:35)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.getDetails(GoogleClientSecrets.java:82)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:197)
>     at
>   tn.esprit.spring.google.calendar.Service.getCredentials(Service.java:75)
>     at
>   tn.esprit.spring.google.calendar.Service.getCalendarService(Service.java:90)
>     at tn.esprit.spring.google.calendar.Service.main(Test.java:102)

it's blocked on `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY).setAccessType("offline").build();`

Could you please tell me what I missed ?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Calendar Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java) and the modify what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use mail user instead:

```
Events events = service.events().list(user@entreprise.tn)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();
```

HTH